# use a child usercontrol button to load another child usercontrol in a grid from a window

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, listview

I am creating a wpf application and in that application there is one window with a grid in it, and in this grid I host my user controls by adding them to the grid,

I have to explain this in detail to show it’s working

so basically there is a side menu, which In actuality is a listview, and when a listview  item is selected or that event is raised, the corresponding user control to that listview item is added to the grid

Well this worked, but this was slow, so instead what I did was load all the user controls to the grid and controlled the visibility property of the user control corresponding to its listview item selected

This is the code that I am using

```
 //Adds usercontrol to grid

 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl usc = null;

        usc = new Home();
        usc.Tag = "Home";
        LoadGrid.Children.Add(usc)
    
        ShowUserControl("Home");
     }


  //controls UserControl visibility

  private void ShowUserContro(string v)

    {
        foreach (UIElement item in LoadGrid.Children)
        {
            if (item is UserControl) 
            {
                UserControl x = (UserControl)item;
                if (x.Tag != null) 
                {
                    if (x.Tag.ToString().ToUpper() == v.ToUpper())
                    {
                        x.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        x.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    //controls listview selection changed event

        private void ListViewMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowUserContro((((ListViewItem)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem).Name));
    }
```

My question is I want the grid to host a user control but it should be tied to a button inside the user control

Example :

*(The main window where the grid is present, children's are added to the grid, and its visibility property which is collapsed and visible, this event is tied up to the listview menu)*

**when lets say a listview item called home is selected, the user control corrosponding to home is added and made visible, this has a button it is supposed to show another user control** *(that hosts a few textbox and data-grid)*

Answer (score 1):

1. You can send the main window as an input parameter to the
   user-controller Constructors and in the main window put the method
   of adding the user-controller and add or manage the user-controller
   there.
2. The next solution is to give an event to the button inside the
   current control and use that event in the main window, and of course
   this method is better.

***MainWindow.cs***

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   MyUserControl myControl = new MyUserControl();
   myControl.ButtonClicked += MyControl_ButtonClicked;
   this.stMain.Children.Add(myControl);
}

private void MyControl_ButtonClicked(object Sender)
{
    //add userControl
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

***MyUserControl.Xaml***

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestProj.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProj"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnAddOtheruserControl" Click="btnAddOtheruserControl_Click" Content="add Another UserControl">         </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

***MyUserControl.cs***

```
 public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventAddAnotherUserControl ButtonClicked;
    public delegate void EventAddAnotherUserControl(object Sender);
    public MyUserControl()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAddOtheruserControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (ButtonClicked != null)
           ButtonClicked(btnAddOtheruserControl);
    }
}
```